# Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise<HTTPResponse>'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to retrieve a list of products via a http call and then pipe and map the result before returning it to the subscribed function.
I am using the ionic cordova advanced http plugin for ssl pinnign and making my requests.
When i try to pipe the result of the request I get the error;

Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Promise'

Any ideas how to get around this?

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, pipe, Observer } from 'rxjs';
import {AuthenticationService} from './authentication.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
import {map, startWith} from "rxjs/operators";

const ENDPOINT_URL = environment.endpointURL;
const CK = environment.consumerKey;
const CS = environment.consumerSecret;
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PricesService {
  products: any;
  private user: any;
  items: any[] = [];
  page = 1;
  api_query = '';
  totalProducts = 1;

  providers: [
    HTTP // <-- List providers here
  ]

  constructor(
    public http: HTTP,
    public authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }


  getPrices(selectedQuantity): Observable<[]> {
    this.api_query = ENDPOINT_URL + 'wc/v3/product?tag=' + selectedQuantity + '?consumer_key=' + CK + '&consumer_secret=' + CS
    return this.http.get(this.api_query, '','').pipe(
      map(resp => {
        let data = resp['body'];

        // for (let post of data) {
        //   post.media_url = post['_embedded']['wp:featuredmedia'][0]['media_details'].sizes['medium'].source_url;
        // }
        return data;
      })
    );
  }

}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import {PricesService} from '../prices.service';
import {AuthenticationService} from '../authentication.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-compare',
  templateUrl: './compare.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./compare.page.scss'],
})
export class ComparePage implements OnInit {
  items: any[];

  constructor(
    public authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    public pricesService: PricesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getPrices(selectedValue) {
    console.log("NEWLY SELECTD VALUE: "+selectedValue);
    //const user = this.authenticationService.getUser();
    console.log('Getting prices');
    this.pricesService.getPrices(selectedValue)
      .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
        this.items = data;
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your source code example. It's a mess. If you want help put some effort into the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enhancement to @Rohit Sharma's answer:

I will suggest that you wrap the from call with the [defer](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/defer) operator. This will make the observable "lazy" so that the underlying request is only made once you `subscribe`.

```js
import { from, defer } from 'rxjs';


return defer(() => from(this.http.get(this.api_query, '','')))
  .pipe(
    map(resp => // return something)
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for this.
Had originally googled, converting a promise into an observable and using the from operator was second result in the list

Answer (score 2):

Because this HTTP get request returns the promise, you need to convert the returned promise into an observable first. To convert the promise into the observable you can use the `from` operator provided by rxjs library

```js
// import 'from' operator from rxjs
import { from } from 'rxjs';

return from(this.http.get(this.api_query, '','')).pipe(
    map(resp => // return something)
);
```

You can read more [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http) about the Native HTTP module of Cordova.

Comment: But since this is Angular, why not suggest the OP to use the HTTPClient, which has an observable based API?

Comment: @AlexBiro Agree, Even I always use the HTTPClient provided by angular core :)

Comment: @RohitSharma the import should be from `'rxjs'`: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/from

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between the typescript declarations and node-fetch code.

Typescript declares `body` attribute as `ReadableStream<Uint8Array>`, but fetch define a `stream.PassThrough`.

So, the next code works for me:

```js
import { PassThrough } from "stream"

interface FetchResponse extends Response {
  readonly body: PassThrough & Response["body"]
  // Or, if you prefer, the following syntax:
  // readonly body: PassThrough & (ReadableStream<Uint8Array> | null)
}

const res = (await fetch(url)) as FetchResponse
```